# Help with the definition of weak solution

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I've just begun studying PDE.

In order to prove that $w \in C^1(D)$ is a weak solution of 
\begin{equation} 
\begin{cases} \Delta\:g+ \lambda \:g=0\quad {\rm in}\;D  \\ g=0\quad {\rm on} \; \partial D\end{cases}
 \end{equation}
should I prove that
 \begin{equation*}
 \int_{D}{\bigtriangledown w\cdot\bigtriangledown \phi\: dx}=\lambda\:\int_{D}{w\:\phi \:dx} \quad{\rm for\; all\;\phi\in{C}_0^\infty  }\quad?
 \end{equation*}
Is this the definition? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is the definition of a *weak solution*. If you will find some $w$, which satisfies this integral equality for all $\phi \in C_0^\infty$, then $w$ is a solution.

Comment: @Voliar Thanks for the answer! Now, by elliptic regularity, can I also conclude that this is a classical solution?

Comment: Yes, you will get interior $C^2$-regularity of the solutions. The regularity up to the boundary $\partial D$ depends on the smoothness of $\partial D$. If $\partial D \in C^2$, then the solution will be $C^2$ (i.e. classical) in $\overline{D}$.